# Text Field as a configurable attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute

I need to allow users to add a string before putting a product in the cart, like a configurable product (for example colors [white, black, yellow, ...]) but without pre-defined strings.

How can I insert a text-input field in the product page and making automatically store these data in the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom form fields.
Edit the product and you should see a tab on the left saying custom fields.
You can add there a textarea field and you should see the value in the order.